# How to enter the text in search bar using UIAutomation?

Tags: ui-automation

Could you please help me out in entering the text in search bar using UIAutomation scripts for IPhone Application.

Thanks in advance,
Madhu.

Answer (score 4):

UIASearchBar inherits from UIATextField:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIASearchBarClassReference/UIASearchBar/UIASearchBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009913

Try the "setValue" method:

```
searchBar.setValue("search for this");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since through tap input method you communicate with the device, you can try user-like type of action: **tapping**.

To bring up the keyboard you just tap on the text input field:

```
someTextInputField.tap();
```

But be aware of the fact that there is no keyboard object instance available for actions if you do not activate the keyboard itself by tapping on any text input field.

Once the keyboard is activated:

```
var App = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp();
var Keyboard = App.keyboard();
var Keys = Keyboard.keys();
var AltKeys = Keyboard.buttons();
```

Where `AltKeys` represent service buttons like *Shift*, *Done*, etc.
And `Keys` represent all other buttons.

P.S. Keep in mind that you have to switch between keyboard tabs to get access to either *characters*, *numbers*, *special characters*.